# Scroll doesn't work in android on using skrollr.js and multiple divs with id "skrollr-body"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, skrollr

I am using skrollr.js for animations and for some reason scroll is not working. Everything is working fine in desktop. As suggested in documentation, I wrapped everything in a div with id "skrollr-body" but when I check the rendered html in browser console, I could see two divs with the same id "skrollr-body". The first one is an empty div and the other div is the wrapper div I added. Please help.

This is the rendered HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="skrollr-body"></div>
    <div class="container" id="content_div">
        <div class="row feature-row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div id="screens_div">
            <img class="img-responsive skrollable skrollable-before" data-anchor-target="#screens_div" data-center-top="transform: rotate(0deg);" data-center-bottom="transform: rotate(90deg);" id="lumia" src="images/lumia.png" style="-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6" id="innovative">
        <h2 style="color:#FF4B25;">INNOVATIVE AD FORMATS</h2>
        <p class="description_paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ut justo tortor. Nulla faucibus aliquet nisi sit amet iaculis. Fusce libero mauris, mollis nec nulla eget, imperdiet blandit lacus. Ut posuere, dolor ac lobortis suscipit, tellus nulla cursus massa, a vulputate sem erat sit amet orci. Nam ut suscipit purus. Ut ut vehicula risus. Vestibulum ac quam sagittis, feugiat velit at, laoreet metus. Aliquam suscipit vulputate risus, eget commodo orci tempor ac. Suspendisse suscipit bibendum risus quis condimentum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>  
    </div>
    <script src="javascripts/skrollr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = skrollr.init({
        forceHeight : false
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Thanks,
Charan.

Comment: please paste some rendered html

Comment: So why add wrapper DIV, just don't add it and see

Comment: Removed wrapper div also, still not working.

Comment: giving this question a +1 vote to counter someone's unexplained downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try when you are " I wrapped everything in a div with id "skrollr-body" but" 
undo that..

now in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#skrollr-body').remove(); //removes the empty div..
    $('#content_div').wrap('<div id="skrollr-body">'); 
});
```

**Updated** - `$('#skrollr-body').remove();` will remove this `<div id="skrollr-body"></div>`

then `$('#content_div').wrap('<div id="skrollr-body">');` will wrap
`<div class="container" id="content_div">` in the required div with a new 
`<div id="skrollr-body">`

your new HTML will look like this:

```
<body>
 <div id="skrollr-body">
  <div class="container" id="content_div">
    <div class="row feature-row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <div id="screens_div">
        <img class="img-responsive skrollable skrollable-before" data-anchor-target="#screens_div" data-center-top="transform: rotate(0deg);" data-center-bottom="transform: rotate(90deg);" id="lumia" src="images/lumia.png" style="-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6" id="innovative">
    <h2 style="color:#FF4B25;">INNOVATIVE AD FORMATS</h2>
    <p class="description_paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ut justo tortor. Nulla faucibus aliquet nisi sit amet iaculis. Fusce libero mauris, mollis nec nulla eget, imperdiet blandit lacus. Ut posuere, dolor ac lobortis suscipit, tellus nulla cursus massa, a vulputate sem erat sit amet orci. Nam ut suscipit purus. Ut ut vehicula risus. Vestibulum ac quam sagittis, feugiat velit at, laoreet metus. Aliquam suscipit vulputate risus, eget commodo orci tempor ac. Suspendisse suscipit bibendum risus quis condimentum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>  
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: can improve if you provide rendered html.

Comment: I am adding skrollr-body to make it work in mobile browser. It is not working even if I removed the id.

Comment: yeah, it'll add the wrapper after making sure to remove the empty one that you spoke about in question.. @charan

Comment: `<div id="skrollr-body"><div>` This is getting added from skrollr.js `<div class="container">Some html</div>`

Comment: this is just getting more confusing charan.. can you add way more details to the question, some html after loading the page + the code (if any) that you used to trigger the plugin on the element.

Comment: I have added the rendered html. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: I already tested your answer but it is still not working in mobile browser. Any idea?

Comment: nah - theres something up with that plugin.. its not formatting itself correctly. sorry.

Comment: My bad. There was mistake in html itself and I didn't notice it. Thanks!

Comment: @charan glad you got it sorted mate :)